# Using found set of records as basis for value list

Tags: find, filemaker

Beginner question.  I would like to have a value list display only the records in a found set.

For example, in a law firm database that has two tables, **Clients** and **Cases**, I can easily create value list that displays all cases for clients.

But that is a lot of cases to pick from, and invites user mistakes.  I would like the selection from the value list to be restricted to cases matched to a particular client.

I have tried this method https://support.claris.com/s/article/Creating-conditional-Value-Lists-1503692929150?language=en_US and it works up to a point, but it requires too much entry of data and too many tables.

It seem like there ought to be a simpler method using the find function.  Any help or ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can easily restrict the selection to cases matched to a particular client by using a **relationship** - but not by performing a find. I don't see why you say that this *"requires too much entry of data and too many tables."*. All you need for this is a table of Clients and a table of Cases, related by by ClientID - and you say you already have this.

Comment: I should also add that you don't have to use a value list to select a case. You could select from a card window showing a list of records - and here you could perform a find to show only relevant cases. Although in the given example it would be sufficient to do `Go to Related Record` instead of an actual find.